# convert total minutes into days, hours, minutes in vb

Tags: vb.net

i want to convert total minutes into days hours and minutes. i am new to vb and still trying to learn...
this is my code...

```
    Private Sub TextBox3_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TextBox3.TextChanged
    TextBox1.Text = TextBox3.Text / 1440
    End Sub


    Private Sub TextBox1_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.TextChanged
    TextBox3.Text = TextBox1.Text * 1440
    TextBox7.Text = TextBox1.Text / 24
    End Sub

    Private Sub TextBox7_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TextBox7.TextChanged
    TextBox1.Text = TextBox7.Text * 24
    End Sub
```

When i run it i am having answers in decimal.. can anyone suggest me a proper way to do this? i do not want decimals.

Comment: Start by turning on `Option Strict` text controls contain text - you cannot do math on text.  You should also name your controls: `tbHours` would make more sense to you in code than `TextBox18`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It doesn't look like you understand the concept of variables, you don't need to have three different handlers to make this work, you can do it all in one handler.

You could do what you want arithmetically but in my opinion, an easier way is to use TimeSpan. It would look something like this:

```
'TextBox1 is where the user inputs the number of minutes
Private Sub TextBox1_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.TextChanged
    Dim d = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(TextBox1.Text) 'creates a TimeSpan based on user input, this is also a variable creation


    TextBox5.Text = d.ToString("dd\:hh\:mm") 'you can format it with a custom format


    'Or you can access the elements of the TimeSpan like so

    TextBox2.Text = d.Days
    TextBox3.Text = d.Hours
    TextBox4.Text = d.Minutes
End Sub
```

Comment: thank you so much for the help... i have one more doubt... i have a field of delay time.. how can i add the delay time to the above code?

Comment: i tried the if then statement but i couldnt get the code working. i want the textbox1 (as in the above code) to add the delay time if mentioned n then convert the total minutes into days, hours and minutes.

Comment: What do you mean delay time? Post your updated code.

Comment: i meant if i need to add a value to the above total number of minutes how do i do it.... @obl

Comment: You should be able to just change the text in the textbox. The "Handles TextBox1.TextChanged" event fires whenever the text in TextBox1 changes.

Comment: can u give me an example?

Comment: I'm still not sure what you mean by adding a value, you just type whatever you want into the textbox and it will show you the formatted string. Can you give me an example of what you want to do?